# What are the most common pitfalls for a beginner Drupal user?

Tags: drupal

I'm just starting to learn [Drupal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drupal), and I am really liking it.

What are the most common pitfalls for a beginner? How can they be avoided?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

First of all you should be clear with yourself on what you are trying to learn:

- Theming?
- Site building?
- Developing new modules/functionality?

Of course the boundaries of each of those areas are not sharp, but the patterns that you will follow to learn about drupal will be quite different. Here's my opinion:

**General pitfall (applies to all areas)**

The single most recurrent mistake beginners do is to be in a hurry. In a world of books with titles like "learn to master C++ in 24 hours or less" people approaches drupal believing that they can get away with a couple of days of playing around with somebody's else code. If they do not understand at first sight how things work in Drupal they switch to *rant mode* and begin to post on blogs and forums on how much drupal is stupidly complicated.

So: be prepared to invest time and energy to embrace the high level of *complexity* (which is something different than *complication*) of Drupal. Be prepared to actually *study* how things work rather than skim over help requests on forums and mailing lists. If you are still not convinced. Here it comes [some good reading](http://norvig.com/21-days.html).

**If you are learning about theming**

- *Pitfall*: learning by trying to hack a previously existing theme.
- *A better way*: first off, give at least a good in-depth look at the Drupal [theming guide](http://drupal.org/theme-guide). It's dry and it's boring but it gives you a good overview of the flow of the theming engine. Then download and install the [zen theme](http://drupal.org/project/zen) and start you theme by using the starter kit that is included. I recommend - if you use Drupal 6 - to use the version 2 of the theme, although in beta, as it has a much more logical organisation of its internal files, at least IMO.

**If you are learning about building sites**

- *Pitfall*: getting overwhelmed by the amount of available modules and missing out on the big ones.
- *A better way*: read some of the [case studies](http://drupal.org/cases) that have been presented over the years on drupal.org. You will get a pretty nice idea of what are common patterns in implementing functionality by means of contributed modules. Explore and understand the core components of drupal well. They are the basis for everything else, so you will definitively need to know how the mechanism of nodes and revision works, what is the functioning of the taxonomy, how the permission/roles system work, what are the differences between nodes and blocks etc... Do not miss out on [CCK](http://drupal.org/project/cck) and [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views), which - although they are (until now) contributed modules, are a component of 99% of the drupal sites "out there".

**If you are learning about writing your own modules**

- *Pitfall*: trying to put together a functionality by mean of assembling PHP and jQuery snippets of code retrieved here and there on the web.
- *A better way of doing*: if you want to be good at drupal you can't afford to go by the *just in time* learning paradigma, you have to go for the old-school *just in case* one. You really need to have a general overall understanding of all the components of the system (amongst others: form API, menu system, hook logic, js in Drupal, node processing, theming engine, localisation, caching...). Drupal is somehow a framework, and if you do not know well the ecosystem in which you are planting your code, chances are you will spent lot of time in producing an horrible code that will soon or later fail in doing what it is supposed to. Above all you will take a lot of time to code something that possibly would have taken a fraction of the time to be realised "the drupal way".

**My opinion about possible tools for learning to code well in drupal**

- **http://drupal.org** - Is packed with useful information, but it is so messy and the ratio signal/noise is so low that I would discourage to use the site as your main source of information.
- **Books** - IMO if you are new to Drupal it might be worth to invest on a couple of books. Books provide that logical structure and learning sequence that you can't have by jumping from one site to the other, following a screencast here and a how-to there. My top three: [Module development](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1847194443) is a book very well written, with a smart progression of topics, it actually guides you to writing a few modules with increasing complexity. It is a good reading to quickly get an idea of how drupal works. [Pro Drupal Develpment](http://www.drupalbook.com/) is *the* book for Drupal. It is quite dry and - although it has examples of code all along - I like it more as a study-book / reference text. Be sure to get the second edition as the first one deals with Drupal 5, which is going to be obsolete soon. The only noticeable shortcoming of Pro Drupal Development is javascript (introduced in a very hasty way). JS and Drupal is a wide topic, and for that purpose I like [Drupal 6 Javascript and jQuery better](http://www.packtpub.com/drupal-6-javascript-and-jquery) as the first book I mentioned, this book is also project-based (i.e. You learn things in relation to the needs to implement a project).
- **Other websites** - They are an invaluable source of information and examples. It is the perfect place to search when you have a general understanding on how to realise things, but too little experience in a specific domain to be autonomous (and everybody, no matter how experienced, have some domains in which they are not "pro"). Some good websites have been already mentioned by others. My all-time favourite is [lullabot](http://www.lullabot.com/) but [drupal dojo](http://drupaldojo.com/) and [learn by the drop](http://learnbythedrop.com/) are also very good.
- **Community** - This is a huge asset of drupal. The community is very big and very helpful and you are likely to all the time find somebody wishing to help. The [IRC channel](http://drupal.org/irc) is a good place to start.
- **Meetings** - Every 6 months the Drupal community meets for a few days (once in North America and once in Europe) to exchange expertise and information. Although travelling to DrupalCon can be (too) expensive for doing it, since a couple of meetings the community got organised to post all the [videos of all the sessions held](http://drupal.org/node/385952). They are an excellent resource too.

Hope this helps to get you going, and best luck with your learning! :)

Answer (score 2):

For Drupal beginners, and "especially" if, like me, one has a firm grasp of MVC or MVP concepts, I would recommend buying or borrowing "Pro Drupal 7 Development", Third Edition.

As for pitfalls:

- Learn the menu (routing) system
- Embrace the Form API
- While some have embraced Zen, I have personally embraced Omega
- As one stated earlier, Views are your friend. Model and create as many "Content Types" as needed, then use Views to display them.
- CTools is great, Views is the best sauce on planet Drupal, but tread lightly around the Panels and Page Manager interface. :)

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

- Learn to theme using the Zen theme or something like it as a base
- Theme fields, not pages
- Views are your friend
- ImageCache rocks

Comment: Why can't I start with a blank theme?

Comment: Well, you can, but Zen is kind of like a blank theme to begin with. Most of its CSS is just resetting browser styles and some of the drupal CSS, plus it adds some nice convenience classes and overrides some templates so they are less annoying.

Answer (score 1):

You could - a lot of people started with the Garland theme that comes with Drupal and got stuck because it has logic in the middle (big no-no in a theme) and renamed its parts confusingly. Zen is documented.

Here's a podcast at Lullabot about it:
http://www.lullabot.com/audiocast/podcast-74-drupal-design-round-table

Answer (score 1):

One common pitfall is not to do enough research on the different modules available for each task or function that you are trying to accomplish.  It is very easy to install a module in Drupal and start working with it without fully understanding the nuances of that module.  It might seem as though the module is working as expected.  However, halfway though your project you might find that that a particular module has a limitation or issue that cannot be overcome without major custom code.  Another module might have been just as appropriate for the project but also met your additional requirement.  A good example of this is deciding how to setup your user permissions.  There are many modules that help enhance Drupal's out of the box permissions system but each one works differently and has a specific feature set.  Do you need special login screens for different users, workflow requirements, etc?  Also included in this is a proper evaluation of whether you should use a module that does not quite meet your needs or write your own instead.  Without fully understanding the limitations of the module as related to your specific requirements you could go down a path where you would spend a lot of time trying to fit the module into your needs instead of just quickly building one from scratch that exactly matches your requirements.