# attach multiple images to a taxonomy term

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules

I have installed "Taxonomy Image" module.
but i can not find a way to attach multiple images to one taxonomy term

my drupal version is 6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a side note to what Henrik answered, an alternate way to implement what you want without having to code a single line could be:

1. Create "image nodes" for each term of your taxonomy.
2. Associate each image node to the right term of the taxonomy (here's where it get interesting: you can create more than one image node per term and can also use the same image node for different terms).
3. Create a [wiew](http://drupal.org/project/views) that takes as arguments the taxonomy term/terms and show all the image nodes tagged with that term.

If you already know the [views module](http://drupal.org/project/views) you probably realise how easy it is. If you are new to Drupal and do not know it yet, then I [recommend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1791553/1792525#1792525) you take a close look at it together with the [CCK](http://drupal.org/project/cck) one: they are big and require some time to be "grokked" (neither so much, though!) but every second you spend studying them is worth it!

Using *views* also gives you **a lot of flexibility** as you can theme easily theme your output in tables, lists, grids, add or remove associated fields, and even put extra filters or expose them to the user in separate blocks...

HTH!

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can see, the module does not provide the option to attach multiple images to one term. From the [features list on the project page](http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_image):

> - Allows one-to-one term-to-image relationships.
> - Allows many-to-one term-to-image relationships.

So one term can have exactly on image, or multiple terms can have the same image (for 'inheritance' of a parent term image), but no 'multiple images per term' option.

I have not delved into the modules code to look if there is an easy way to change this, though. So far, [there seems to be no request for this feature](http://drupal.org/project/issues/search/taxonomy_image?text=&assigned=&submitted=&participant=&status[]=Open&categories[]=feature&issue_tags_op=or&issue_tags=) either.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to first install the following modules:

- [Views Bulk Operations](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations)
- [Administration Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/admin_views)

After enabling both modules. Go to Admin >> Structure >> Views and edit the Administration: Files view. Add the desired taxonomy field.

Go back to the Administration >> Content >> File and there you`ll see now operations, select change value and the desired images you wish to have the same taxonomy term.  Click Execute >> Your taxonomy field. Select the term or terms and click next. That is it.