# Drupal CCK filefield variable access

Tags: php, drupal, cck

Just wondering can anyone tell me how to access the file field variable in drupal?  I can access the rest of the node's variabels with the following php:

$node->field_event[0]['value'];

But I do not know how to access the content of a file field called field_pdf.

I know it is created with something like:

$node->field_pdf = array(
    array(
      'fid' => $file->fid,
      'title' => basename($file->filename),
      'filename' => $file->filename,
      'filepath' => $file->filepath,
      'filesize' => $file->filesize,
      'mimetype' => $mime,
      'description' => basename($file->filename),
      'list' => 1,
    ),
  );

I solved thie problem with the following snippet:

$node->field_pdf[0]['filepath'];

Hope this helps somebody.

j

Comment: you might as well ask on drupal support forums (http://drupal.org/forum) or on drupal irc channels (http://drupal.org/irc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not 100% sure I got what your doubt is, however on a node with a file_field (a series of PDF attachments in my case) the `$node` object has a property called `files` which structure is like this:

```
[files] => Array
    (
        [190] => stdClass Object
            (
                [fid] => 190
                [uid] => 1
                [filename] => attachmentname.pdf
                [filepath] => sites/default/files/attachmentname_0.pdf
                [filemime] => application/pdf
                [filesize] => 295159
                [status] => 1
                [timestamp] => 1255855095
                [nid] => 36644
                [vid] => 36603
                [description] => attachmentdescription
                [list] => 1
                [weight] => 0
            )
```

I also suggest you install [drupalforfirebug](http://drupal.org/project/drupalforfirebug) this is an awesome module that - in combination with firebug - allows you to see the structure of all your nodes / forms / user objects, etc... very handy!

HTH.

PS: If this is not what you are looking for, please specify in a comment how can I help better.

Comment: Thanks for the drupalforfirebug tip.  I'm a newbie with drupal so still learning the ropes. 

I have one file tupe with the node specified by the field_pdf.  From your suggestion, I think I can access the file path with this:

$node->files[0]['filepath'];

Is this correct?

Thanks for your help, much appreciated.  

j

Comment: Welcome to the Drupal community, then! A few days back somebody posted a couple of questions about learning Drupal, in case you are interested: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1791553/the-most-common-pitfalls-for-a-beginner-drupal-user and 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1791035/good-beginners-material-advice-on-drupal, but if you search here on SO you will find also other older post with a similar focus.

Comment: Cheers, I bought a couple of those books already.  Just trying to get as familar as possible at the moment. 
 thanks again,

j